# Spring Security authorization of expect request

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get a reset/password url to work with my spring security.   Everytime that I call this url I am getting a 401.

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint());


http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/password/reset").permitAll();

http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login").permitAll();


http.addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter("/api/login", tokenAuthenticationService, userDetailsService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
http.addFilterAfter(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

http.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll();

http.logout()
        .deleteCookies("remove")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .logoutUrl("/api/logout");
```

Any ideas why spring is throwing a 401?

Many thanks

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the user authenticated?  Your config says so:

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
```

I would move the reset to a non-authenticated part:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/password/reset").permitAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/password/reset");
    }
```